# Mimic a value lookup in Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to implement EF with an existing table structure that I'm not allowed to alter to be able to persist data.

I have `TableA` with columns like so:

```
EntityCode
EntityName
...
```

`EntityCode` is the primary key of a table called `Entities` with columns like so:

```
EntityCode
EntityName
```

The data in memory contains only the `EntityCode` for the `TableA` record.  I need to populate `TableA`.`EntityName` when inserting the record.

The current code for persistance simply does a lookup first (`SELECT EntityName FROM Entities WHERE EntityCode='blah`).

How do I (can I) mimic this behavior in EF 4.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
TableAObject tableA = new TableAObject() { EntityCode = "123" };
//...
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    tableA.EntityName = context.Entities
        .Where(e => e.EntityCode == tableA.EntityCode)
        .Select(e => e.EntityName)
        .SingleOrDefault();

    context.TableAObjects.Add(tableA);
    context.SaveChanges();        
}
```